# How can i destroy & reinit singleton class

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

```
+(id)sharedInstance{
    static MusicHelper *objManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{
        objManager = [[MusicHelper alloc]init];
    });
    return objManager;
}
```

- I am using above code for singleton class. I want to destroy and reinit it.

Comment: That does sound like a red flag. If you _need_ to do this, rather than say _reset_ the `sharedInstance`, it could indicate that using a singleton is not the right solution in the first place...

Comment: Ive had use cases where its useful to have, say a singleton that should only exist while the user is logged in, then you would want to destroy/reinit when logging out, also destroy and reinit is just a lazy way of resetting really

Comment: If you reInint you will lose already set data

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick (untested, did off top of my head, but should give you the gist)

```
static MusicHelper *objManager;

+(id)sharedInstance{

    if(objManager == nil)
        objManager = [[MusicHelper alloc]init];
    }
    return objManager;
}

+(void) destroyInstance {
    objManager = nil;
}
```

Comment: How can in reinit it

Comment: just call `sharedInstance` again after `destroyInstance`, and it will make the new singleton